# If I take the "food addiction" flaw, does the type of food I eat matter?

Tags: the-outer-worlds

In "The Outer Worlds" (PC via Steam), I took the "Food Addiction" flaw for my character in exchange for an extra perk. Now I periodically get a negative debuff which requires me to eat a food item to alleviate.

I've been eating either Raptidon Meat (because it weighs 1 lb) or food with buffs that last a very short amount of time (15-20 seconds). I'm wondering if it makes a difference what kind of food specifically I eat. Do the negative effects stay away longer if I eat higher quality food (eg food whose buffs last 1-2 minutes), or is it all equal?

I've personally not noticed any difference, but at the same time I'm also busy trying not to die, so there's that. I'm playing on Normal difficulty. (This is my first play-through, please no spoilers!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lacking any documentation, I ran a little experiment and determined that *all* food gives you **8 realtime minutes** before you need to eat again.

I ran the experiment with the following items:

- Knock You Out Bar (Carbs, 20 seconds)
- Mock Apple (Carbs, 2 minutes)
- Gourmet Saltuna Fillets (Meat, 2 minutes)

In all cases, the time that the negative effects were staved off were approximately 8 minutes, give or take a few seconds (which could be attributed to measurement error, or the fact that I did drop into TTD once or twice to fight the locals while strolling across Monarch's wilderness.)

Tha being said, those 8 realtime minutes *did* include cinematic deathcams and companion attacks, so it's not "8 minutes as you walk around" but *actual* realtime minutes. It *doesn't* appear to include the loading screen time when you fast travel or transition from one area to another. I'm unsure how time spent futzing around in inventory or at vendors is counted; I may run another experiment to figure this out.

---

After some more observations and experimentation, I've determined the following:

- Sleeping will remove the negative effects of food withdrawal. This is likely a bug since it doesn't really make any logical sense.
- Food withdrawal will not kill you. (In comparison to actual hunger in supernova, which eventually will.)
- The food withdrawal debuff appears more often than regular hunger in supernova mode; thus if you keep your addiction satisfied you'll never get "normally" hungry.